# How to run Netbeans 8.0 as root

Tags: netbeans

I've installed Netbeans 8.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. After that I updated the operating system and now the Ubuntu version is 14.04.

Netbeans was installed in the default folder. I did not specify any custom folder for installation.

Netbeans asked to install updates, but was unable to continue the operation, because Netbeans was not running under root permissions.

How can I start Netbeans with root permissions?

What `sudo` command should be executed in terminal to launch Netbeans as root?

I searched this in Google but did not find a working answer.

Comment: @karel I don't think the question is asking that, but rather what the command is to launch Netbeans.

Comment: It's both I guess. The OP wants to open NetBeans, which is a graphical app, as root in order to install updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not advised to use sudo against graphical applications, try to run it with gksu:

```
gksu netbeans
```

Or if the executable is not systemwide, cd to where it is located and:

```
gksu ./netbeans
```

Comment: what path should I navigate to run this command? (Ubuntu is running on x86 PC). There's the path: `~/.netbeans/8.0/bin/nativeexecution/Linux-x86` where I assume Netbeans should start. But nothing happens except of asking administrative password. Ubuntu asks for admin password and does nothing afterwards.

Comment: I assumed the executable was under your home directory. I just checked and mine is in /usr/bin/netbeans so try "gksu /usr/bin/netbeans" If it doesn't work, locate that file with "locate netbeans".

Comment: I ran `gksu /usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans` and it worked. Thank you.